# Nodejs Create excel (csv/xlsx) buffer file from json

Tags: json, node.js, excel, csv

I am looking for library which will create excel file ( csv and xlsx ) from from json

I have array of objects

```
var arr=[
    {
        "name": "Ivy Dickson",
        "date": "2013-05-27T11:04:15-07:00",
        "number": 10
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-02-07T22:09:58-08:00",
        "name": "Walker Lynch",
        "number": 2
    },
    {
        "number": 5,
        "date": "2013-06-16T05:29:13-07:00",
        "name": "Maxwell U. Holden"
    },
    {
        "name": "Courtney Short",
        "date": "2014-03-14T07:32:34-07:00",
        "number": 6
    }
]
```

and I want to convert it into excel file buffer.

I am not getting which library is best for my condition.

please suggest better library.

Answer (score 2):

You have that package [json2xls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2xls), it's really easy to use, but it's only for convert json in excel file.

But you have a other package for convert json in csv, it's [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv).